# How to find the existence criterion for real solution on the complex Vandermonde system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Given postive integer $M \in \mathbb{N}$, **find the condition on the the combination of $distinct$ $p$ integers** $$i_{0}, i_{1}, \ldots, i_{p-1} \in \{0,1,\ldots,M-1 \}, \omega = e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{M}}$$ such that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
\omega^{i_0} \\ 
\omega^{i_1} \\
\omega^{i_2} \\
\vdots \\ 
\omega^{i_{p-1}}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \omega^{-i_0} & \ldots  & \omega^{-(p-1)i_0}\\ 
1 & \omega^{-i_1} & \ldots  & \omega^{-(p-1)i_1}\\ 
1 & \omega^{-i_2} & \ldots  & \omega^{-(p-1)i_2}\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
1 & \omega^{-i_{p-1}} & \ldots  & \omega^{-(p-1)i_{p-1}}
\end{bmatrix} K
$$
has **real** solution $K \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$.

### What I have found

1. when $ p = M$, there  is always a real solution and the real solution is $\begin{bmatrix} 0&   0  \ldots & 1\end{bmatrix}$
2. when $p < M$, I can just naively use the rank test in real matrix form, but, is there any better result we can obtain?

### Update:

For $p<M$, and for particularly searching for *zero-end* solution, like $\begin{bmatrix} 0&   0  \ldots & 1\end{bmatrix}$, I have found a systematic way to do so.

But in practice, there are no-zero end solution which makes the problem harder.